# It is possible in PHP that we can create any public method and use everywhere/anywhere?

Tags: php, function, class, globalization

To track application flow I use a log file and for this, I need to create this function every time

```
    public function lol($lol)
    {
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/test.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info('Simple Text Log'); // Simple Text Log
        $logger->info('AT : '. $lol); // Simple Text Log
        
    }
```

and call it to any line of the class file

`$this->lol(__FILE__."::".__LINE__);`

So, I am finding a way for it, and after creating this function as Global and use anywhere in my any application without extending any class or import any file.

Thank you @community in advance

Answer (score 1):

create PHP Trait for it like this in seperate file .

trait Logger
{
public function log(...$arguements)
{
//your code
}
}

And in your class import this trait like this.

use Namespace\Traits\Logger;

class YourClass
{
use Logger;

```
log(/**...*/);
```

}

Comment: Thank u bro but If I need to track another class then I need to add that class in that class...
No, I am finding a way just like the CodeIgniter helper class 
Ex: Crate function in helper once and Use that function anywhere in the application